# How to use a condition in react component within semantic ui dropdown menu component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I would like to build a little dropdown menu (I'm using semantic-ui-react). But in my case I need a condition depending part of this menu.

This is what I came up with, but it won't work, as it would have to be wrapped. So how should I create this dropdown menu in a correct way to get two menu subblocks with header, divider and items if the `ifThisIsTrue` has true value?

```
render() {
    const ifThisIsTrue = true
    return (
        <Dropdown icon='cogs' className='icon settings'>
            <Dropdown.Menu>
                {
                    ifThisIsTrue &&
                        <Dropdown.Header icon='cogs' content='Label' />
                        <Dropdown.Divider />
                        <Dropdown.Item value='default'>Standard</Dropdown.Item>
                        <Dropdown.Item value='something'>Something</Dropdown.Item>
                        <Dropdown.Item value='else'>Else</Dropdown.Item>
                }

                <Dropdown.Header icon='cogs' content='Edit' />
                <Dropdown.Divider />
                <Dropdown.Item>Delete</Dropdown.Item>
                <Dropdown.Item>Edit</Dropdown.Item>
            </Dropdown.Menu>
        </Dropdown>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the conditional elements in an array (separated by commas, of course). You'll need to give each item a `key` property. React will take care of the rest.

```js
const Component = ({ifThisIsTrue}) => (
  <ul>
    <li>One</li>
    { ifThisIsTrue && [
        <li key="2">Two</li>,
        <li key="3">Three</li>
      ]
    }
  </ul>
);

ReactDOM.render(<Component ifThisIsTrue={Math.random() > 0.5}/>, document.querySelector('div'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Did not know this. Cool. But then I have to add keys, right?

Comment: @user3142695 Yes, you're correct. Good catch. (I forgot that SO snippets use `react.min.js` by default, so it didn't log a warning.) I've edited my answer.